# Not receiving list from documents from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I'm creating a application for clothing stores, I has a Home Screen, login screen, register, etc.

I'having problems gathering some collection and documents from the current user, this collection will build a card with the items that they have in the cart.
This is how my cartManager is built:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/cart_product.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/product.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/user.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/user_manager.dart';

class CartManager {
  List<CartProduct> items = [];

  User? user;

  void updateUser(UserManager userManager) {
    user = userManager.user;
    items.clear();

    if (user != null) {
      _loadCartItems();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _loadCartItems() async {
    final QuerySnapshot cartSnap = await user!.cartReference.getDocuments();

    items = cartSnap.documents.map((d) => CartProduct.fromDocument(d)).toList();
    print(items);
  }

  void addToCart(Product product) {
    items.add(CartProduct.fromProduct(product));
  }
}
```

In the print(items) I'm receiving null although I have items in the cart (firebase).

This is the user page:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class User {
  User({this.email, this.password, this.name, this.id});

  User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    id = document.documentID;
    name = document.data['name'];
    email = document.data['email'];
  }

  String? name;
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? confirmPassword;
  String? id;

  DocumentReference get firestoreRef =>
      Firestore.instance.document('users/$id');

  CollectionReference get cartReference =>
      Firestore.instance.collection('cart');

  Future<void> saveData() async {
    await firestoreRef.setData(toMap());
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'name': name, 'email': email};
  }
}
```

And this is the cart product, the prints are not even being runned:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/item_size.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/product.dart';

class CartProduct {
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

  CartProduct.fromProduct(this.product) {
    productId = product?.id;
    quantity = 1;
    size = product?.selectedSize!.name;
  }

  CartProduct.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    productId = document.data['pid'] as String;
    print(productId);
    print('here');
    quantity = document.data['quantity'] as int;
    size = document.data['size'] as String;

    firestore
        .collection('products')
        .document(productId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => product = Product.fromDocument(doc));
  }

  String? productId;
  int? quantity;
  String? size;

  Product? product;

  ItemSize? get itemSize {
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (product == null) return null;
    return product?.findSize(size!);
  }

  num get unitPrice {
    if (product == null) return 0;
    return itemSize?.price ?? 0;
  }
}
```

I have some photos from my DB, each user has his cart, which makes a reference for another collection which has the products:
[User cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDkIB.png)

This is the product collection:
[Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYBc9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are incorrectly referencing the users cart collection here

```
CollectionReference get cartReference =>
  Firestore.instance.collection('cart');
```

based on the image from your firestore structure I think you should reference the cart collection like this

```
CollectionReference get cartReference =>
  Firestore.instance.collection('users/$id/cart');
```